# How to select elements with part of attribute's value is between two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have these elements

```
<p id="item_1"></p>
<p id="item_5"></p>
<p id="item_200"></p>
<!-- many items with id='item_[200 to 500]' -->
<p id="item_500"></p>
<p id="item_502"></p>
<p id="item_900"></p>
```

I need to make a selector using jQuery to select items b/w 200 and 500

e.g.

```
$('p [id="item_%n>200%n<500"]')
```

Comment: There is no range selector if I am not mistaken.

Comment: you can add a filter and use a regex. I use James Padolsey's implementation for my work. here is the link for your reference https://j11y.io/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Comment: @AnandShanbhag, such an **awesome solution**! I'm gonna dissect it and learn it for fun and necessity! **Thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In this particular case:**

1. get the `p` elements with their ids starting with `item_`
2. filter their ids according to your limits (`n > 200 && n < 500`)
3. use the elements in the `filtered` variable according to your needs.

```js
var filtered = $('p[id^="item_"]').filter(function (index, element) {
  var n = parseInt(element.id.split('_')[1], 10);  
  return n > 200 && n < 500;  
});

filtered.each(function (index, element) {
  console.log(element.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="item_1"></p>
<p id="item_5"></p>
<p id="item_199"></p>
<!-- many items with id='item_[200 to 500]' -->
<p id="item_200"></p>
<p id="item_201"></p>
<p id="item_300"></p>
<p id="item_400"></p>
<p id="item_499"></p>
<p id="item_500"></p>
<p id="item_501"></p>
<p id="item_502"></p>
<p id="item_900"></p>
```

**OR ES6:**

```js
const filtered = $('p[id^="item_"]').filter((index, element) => {
  const n = parseInt(element.id.split('_')[1], 10);  
  return n > 200 && n < 500;  
});

filtered.each((index, element) => console.log(element.id))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="item_1"></p>
<p id="item_5"></p>
<p id="item_199"></p>
<!-- many items with id='item_[200 to 500]' -->
<p id="item_200"></p>
<p id="item_201"></p>
<p id="item_300"></p>
<p id="item_400"></p>
<p id="item_499"></p>
<p id="item_500"></p>
<p id="item_501"></p>
<p id="item_502"></p>
<p id="item_900"></p>
```

**OR "the dirty one-liner":**

***Remark: The solution below is presented for the case of possibility. I strongly discourage the usage of such condensed and unnecessarily compact code below.***

```js
const filtered = $('p[id^="item_"]').filter((idx, el) => (n => n > 200 && n < 500)(parseInt(el.id.split('_')[1], 10)));

filtered.each((idx, el) => console.log(el.id))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="item_1"></p>
<p id="item_5"></p>
<p id="item_199"></p>
<!-- many items with id='item_[200 to 500]' -->
<p id="item_200"></p>
<p id="item_201"></p>
<p id="item_300"></p>
<p id="item_400"></p>
<p id="item_499"></p>
<p id="item_500"></p>
<p id="item_501"></p>
<p id="item_502"></p>
<p id="item_900"></p>
```